# how to show json data in jquery datatable

Tags: java, jquery, json, postgresql, datatables

This is my jquery datatable ajax request... in success im getting the json data but in datatable its not showing ..its showing only loading..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function inituserdatatable() {

  alert("in");
  try {
    $('#userdetailDatatable').DataTable({

      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,

      "ajax": {
        "url": "ps/getUserDetails",
        "type": "post",
        "datatype": "json",
        "success": function(data) {



        },

      },

      "columns": [{
          'data': 'name'
        },
        {
          'data': 'email_id'
        },
        {
          'data': 'user_name'
        },
        {
          'data': 'password'
        }
      ],
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
    });
  } catch (exp) {
    alert(exp);
  }
}
</script>
```

This is my `json` data from `postgresql`

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "",
    "email_id": "",
    "user_name": "",
    "password": ""
  }, {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Ss",
    "email_id": "sd",
    "user_name": "g",
    "password": "g"
  }]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following `processing` and `serverSide` options, they are not needed based on your data format.